# How to display successive frames with opencv

Tags: opencv

I'm looking for a solution to display successive frames in one window using OpenCV. I have a sequence of images (`001.jpg`, `002.jpg`, `003.jpg`, etc.), but not a video. I have to display them within a loop.

The standard code to display an image is:

```
IplImage* src = cvLoadImage("001.jpg");
cvNamedWindow("My pic"); 
cvShowImage("My pic",src); 
cvWaitKey();
```

Comment: If you don't have too many pictures you can load them all and store them in an array of IplImage. Then with a loop of the form : for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {if (i == n) i = 0; .........} you could pass trough all of them in a loop until lets say you press a key (cvWaitKey()).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Link suggests, one option would be to write a function that automatically generates the correct filename, for example:

```
void loadImage(IplImage *image, int number)
{
    // Store path to directory
    char filename[100];
    strcpy(filename, "/path/to/files");

    // Convert integer to char    
    char frameNo[10];
    sprintf(frame, "%03i", number);

    // Combine to generate path
    strcat(filename, frameNo);
    strcat(filename, ".bmp");

    // Use path to load image
    image = cvLoadImage(filename);
}
```

This could then be used in a loop for a known number of images

```
IplImage *im;
for (int i = 0; i < nImages; ++i)
{
    loadImage(im, i);

    /*
        Do stuff with im
    */
}
```

An alternative option would be to investigate the [boost directory iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html).

Answer (score 1):

@Chris code works, I want to add an even simpler routine

```
void loadImage()
{
int nImages = 6;
for (int i = 0; i < nImages; ++i) 
{
IplImage *image;
char filename[100];
strcpy(filename, "images/");

char frameNo[10];
sprintf(frameNo, "%03i", i);

strcat(filename, frameNo);
strcat(filename, ".jpg");

image = cvLoadImage(filename);
cvNamedWindow("pic");
cvShowImage("pic",image);
cvWaitKey(1000);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use XML/YAML persistence mechanisms of OpenCV. Write a list of image paths for loading and use a loop to read those paths and load images. In the example of stereo calibration such a list is used (there is a [directory with examples](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/samples) installed with OpenCV).

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for your answers, but this is actually useful when I don't have many pictures. In my case I have more than 1000 pictures, that I have to process.

Comment: allright, are they named in some generic and easy to automatically write down way? I have a database of almost 600 pictures to work with so I understand the problem. You don't have to write it manually. Just make a loop that generates the names of those files, and write those names into the xml file. Sth like this:
  fs<<ADDRESS<<"[";`
        for(unsigned j=0;j<_gal[i].photos.size();++j){
          fs<<_gal[i].photos[j];
        }
         fs<<"]"<<"}";

_gal[int].photos[int] returns a string with path to a picture file.